# Autoposting to Facebook page from django-rest-framework app

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-rest-framework

I have a simple Django Rest Framework app running. I want to auto post to app's Facebook page whenever new item is saved in the db. I was wondering if Django management commands is the best solution. The other option is google cloud functions to make a request at specified time and post to Facebook if there are new items (could be expensive and unnecessarily complex).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to your item model's `post_save` signal and connect it to a handler function which is responsible for posting your saved item data to a Facebook page. Refer to this [Django Docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders) on how to connect your handler to a signal.

For better performance, posting to a Facebook page can be done asynchronously by leveraging task queue like [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) so it won't affect your REST API response time.

Comment: Thanks,I will dig into it.